# Git is allways showing "Broken pipe, cant write". Where can i see further information?

Tags: ubuntu, git

I use ubuntu and get always the error "broken pipe, cant write". Where can i see the log files to get further information about the errors? The error occurs when i try to do a fetch or a pull.

Comment: Please post the actual command(s) that is giving the error. Is the git repo local or remote? The more information you give the likelier it is you will get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting SIGPIPE signal to your application.
Please see this,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108183/how-to-prevent-sigpipes-or-handle-them-properly